# Adding meta info or tags to Twilio Programmable Video invitation

Tags: twilio

I am working on a web-based video conference system using Twilio. One issue I have is that I want to need to send additional information to the invitee so that they can make a more informed decision about whether they should accept or decline the invitation (for example, are they in the same 'chat room').

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I did not see anything in the Twilio docs.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't provide any of that sort of thing for you, but you could absolutely build it yourself.

For example, when your user receives an [invite](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/0.13.10/docs/IncomingInvite.html) to a [Video chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) that invite will have the identity of the user that wants to chat. With that identity, you can look up the user details in your system, perhaps by an Ajax request.

```
client.on('invite', function(invite) {
  var identity = invite.from;
  // look up user based on identity
});
```

Let me know if that helps at all.